# Is there any method to update a collection single value record and keep the old data too?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to update any one value (Lets say `"CAD": 92.8`) but in the new record, All the other values should remain previous one but the `"CAD": 92.8` should be changed.

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "615564fbab33d4da1ab2d9bb"
    },
    "AUD": 100,
    "CAD": 92.8,
    "CHF": 69.14,
    "EUR": 63.03,
    "GBP": 54.22,
    "KWD": 22.49,
    "TRY": 648.18,
    "USD": 74.65,
    "XNA": 100000,
    "NewMembershipInvest": 80,
    "MembershipYearlyInvest": 1,
    "date": {
        "$date": "2021-09-30T07:19:23.007Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
```

For the updating of the given record I am writing this code and its working fine.

```
router.put('/memfeeput', async (req, res) => {
 let _id="615564fbab33d4da1ab2d9bb";
var doc= {
  TNAME:req.body.tname,
  TVALUE:req.body.tvalue
  }
  console.log([req.body.tname]);
  MemberFee.findOneAndUpdate({_id: _id}, {$set:{[doc.TNAME]:req.body.tvalue}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(doc);
});
});
```

But i want the field to be updated in the new record so that only the updating field value is changed and rest of the values remain same as previous.
What should i do for this updation of value by new record insertion (while other values remain previous one) or are there any other alternatives?

Comment: You want to access/read the existing document, change a field value in that document and write the document as a new document. That requires two database operations - read, and insert (and before the insert change the required value). To make the whole operation _atomic_ use a Transaction.

Comment: Yes it is like this. How can i do this?